# Change the USB pins on SAMD21

Tags: usb, atmel, samd21

I would like to use the pin mux in the SAMD21 mcu, to set different pins for the USB peripheral. The datasheet makes it sound like it is possible, but is very confusing.

datasheet : https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Boards/Atmel-42181-SAM-D21_Datasheet.pdf

Comment: I haven't seen a device that can pin mux the USB, I don't believe the D21 is any different. Which variant are you using?

Comment: @RonBeyer pg 745 "31.5.1 I/O Lines
The USB pins may be multiplexed with the I/O lines Controller. The user must first configure the I/O Controller to assign the USB pins to their peripheral functions." However, I think that just means sharing pins with other functions, not that you can select from multiple pins for USB. Because I saw no duplicate USB in the pinouts.

Comment: as said on this very same [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66067/how-to-change-the-usb-pins-on-samd21?noredirect=1#comment133910_66067) that you asked on DSP.SE, this needs to explain where you're stuck, and what your precise question is.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Your comments at DSP.SE stated that someone certainly had achieved this. Are you not willing to share where you obtained that information?

Comment: @Marchingband I know that someone achieved this, not how. Also, you're still not asking a precise question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller are you sure? Do you have a link or an image or any information at all to share? It seems like it is almost certainly not possible. I have no idea how I could state the question with any more precision. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably referring to this paragraph:

[image]

Which means that you can use the USB lines as I/O lines (if you don't need USB).